# How to retrieve data from api with a lot of dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, im having some trouble iterating through the data i want in api. I have an api like this:

```
{
  "datatype": "text",
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "09/08/09",
      "events": [
        {
          "eventDate": "2017-08-05T00:00:00.000",
          "dataValues": [
            {
              "displayName": "Name",
              "value": "Josh"
            },
            {
              "displayName": "Surname",
              "value": "Rashford"
            },
            {
              "dataElement": "Birth date",
              "value": "09/11/1999"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "eventDate": "2017-08-05T00:00:00.000",
          "dataValues": [
            {
              "displayName": "Name",
              "value": "Josh"
            },
            {
              "displayName": "Surname",
              "value": "Rashford"
            },
            {
              "dataElement": "Birth date",
              "value": "09/11/1999"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

my code

```js
 < table className = "table table-bordered" > < thead > < tr > < th scope = "col" > Date < /th> < th scope = "col" > Name < /th> < th scope = "col" > Surname < /th> < /tr> < /thead> < tbody > {
    (state.data || []).map((data) => (
        (data.events || []).map((details) => (
            (details.dataValues || []).map((value) => (
                ((details.eventDate === '2017-08-05T00:00:00.000')) ? ( < tr > > < td > {
                    details.eventDate
                } < /td> < td > {
                    details.dataValues.filter(x => x.displayName === 'Name')[0].value
                } < /td>   < td > {
                    details.dataValues.filter(x => x.displayName === 'Surname')[0].value
                } < /td>   < /tr>) : (null)))))))
} < /tbody> < /table>
```

I got the the data from the api in the table but the iteration may be wrong and each row is repeated 4 times. I think there's a better way to iterate through the api but im not succeeding in finding it and only get errors when reducing the mapppings. How can i get the data in the table without the repetition?

Comment: What's your expected ouput? I think you're confused on how to use `map` function.

Comment: I want to display the data in the table. I get the data but but each row repeats 4 times

Comment: So from above data, you want to be able to display 2 rows only?

Comment: yes thats the output i want

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63592968/11057988)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `[0].value` with `map(e => e.value)`. This will transform each value in the array instead of using the first one indexed at `0`.

Here is what you need:

```js
<td>
    {
        details.dataValues.filter(x=>x.displayName==='Name').map(e => e.value)
    }
</td>  
<td>
    {
        details.dataValues.filter(x=>x.displayName==='Surname').map(e => e.value)
    }
</td>
```

Comment: thank you. I implemented your solution and additionaly removed the last mapping and now it works